# Why is this proof of squeeze theorem flawed?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have attempted a proof of the squeeze theorem which later turned up as a question in the book where the question was to find the flaw in this very proof.

If $x_n$ is convergent and $s_n \le x_n \le t_n$, and $s_n$ and $t_n$ converge to $L$, then given the order property of limits,

$\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n \le \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n \le \lim_{n\to \infty} t_n$

Thus $L \le \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n \le L$, and this can only be true if $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = L$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to show existence.  As it stands, your argument could probably  be fleshed out to show that $\{x_n\}$ can't approach any limit other than $L$, but that would still leave the possibility that it might not approach a limit at all.

Comment: @lulu "If $x_n$ is convergent" is at the start of the statement.

Comment: @Arthur  Ah, true.  Missed that.  Though the point of the Squeeze Theorem is that the assumptions imply the existence of the limit.

Comment: Which book is that? (I mean, what *exactly* does the question in the book look like? Is there some detail that you may have omitted from the above post?)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Elementary Real Analysis by Thomson and Bruncker

Comment: Just looked it up. The Squeeze Theorem (Th. 2.20) does not assume up-front that $x_n$ is convergent - this is the conclusion of the theorem. The “careless student” (Ex. 2.8.3) does not assume that *either*, but somehow “passes the limit” through the inequality - that is the flaw. You *do* assume $x_n$ to be convergent, so *your* proof is correct, but what you have proven is *not* Squeeze Theorem but a weaker statement. Refer to [some pdf of the book I found online](https://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf). So @lulu ‘s guess was pretty much spot-on.